# How to handle kernel-headers when switching between kernels

Tags: linux, kernel

Many developers at my company need to switch back and forth between two versions of the kernel (in this case, Fedora).  These users need to build kernel modules as well as userspace apps, so they need the **kernel-devel** and **kernel-headers** packages that are associated with the version of the kernel they are currently using.

Both versions of the kernel-devel package are installed, and work without issue.  But installing the kernel-headers package replaces whatever files are already in `/usr/include/linux`.

Questions:

1. Is there a clean way to switch back and forth between multiple kernels without having to reinstall the appropriate version of kernel-headers each time?
2. Because the kernel-headers package seems to be updated only if necessary when a new kernel version is released, the kernel-headers version won't necessarily match the most recent compatible kernel version.  I  understand that the answer might be distro specific, but is there an easy way to determine the latest kernel-headers version used by a particular kernel?

Comment: Offhand, this sounds like a version control issue. Each developer needs to check out the headers appropriate for which they are currently working with.  (This may require a copy of the installed headers to a different location for version control and switching between them.)

Comment: In RPM-land, the kernel headers version number will match the kernel RPM that is installed. That said, it _won't_ match the running the kernel version until rebooted.

Comment: Have you looked at building in a container or chroot that has all the correct packages installed?  I do this all the time with `mock` on Fedora to build kmods for specific kernels